# Wireshark capture HTTP/2 traffic

Tags: wireshark, http2

I am running Wireshark (2.0.2) in Ubuntu 14.04 and trying to capture HTTP/2 traffic. I have added below settings.

Display Filter - http2

Capture Filter - tcp port 443

But I don't see any traffic captured for the pages I access over HTTP/2.

[image]

Comment: HTTP/2 can (by default) go over port 80 and 443 [see here](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/), you're sure you're not using port 80?
Also, you don't use a proxy, right? Does normal web traffic show up?

Comment: Are  you seeing traffic to and from port 443?  If so, is it identified by Wireshark as SSL or TLS?

Comment: First of all you should define `SSLKEYLOGFILE` variable which point to the file which will hold the SSL/TLS keys. After that you should restart Chrome/Firefox and restart WireShark. It allows to decode TTL traffic and to to be able to catch HTTP2. I'm not sure that you will see all the traffic in the way, but at least someone. If you want catch the traffic of *your own web server* and you have private keys, then you can configure SSL protocol to use the key and you will see full HTTP2 traffic.

Comment: Yes. After setting SSLKEYLOGFILE variable it started to work. Followed https://ismisepaul.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/http2-traffic-in-wireshark/